# Can Cloud Run be used for real-time multi-room audio chat with Websockets?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, websocket, google-cloud-run

First I'd like to point out that I'm brand new to Google Cloud Platform, and even to the cloud world as a whole.

I'm currently programming a mobile app using Expo and Firebase.

Basically, I want to create a real-time multi-room chat, with 2 users per room.   I need to send a continuous audio stream from user A's microphone directly to the server, process the audio on the server side as it comes in, and send audio files to user B. When I establish the 'connexion' between A and B (through the server), I already know who are the two members of the room.

So I'd like to use websockets on both sides.

Now, I'm wondering whether Cloud Run is the most suitable backend.
 I don't quite understand whether one instance of Cloud Run is capable of managing several simultaneous rooms, or whether one instance = one room.

I came across this tutorial, which seems far too complex given that I don't need to replicate messages across instances, since I want both websockets connections for the same conversation to be handled by the same instance (if that's possible). https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/websockets

To respect quotas, a conversation will last no more than 60 minutes.

So I have two questions: 
Have I misunderstood something ?  Is Cloud Run best suited for this use ? I'd like to stay serverless.

Thanks for your answers!

I started with Cloud Functions, which are already integrated into Firebase. But I saw on the Internet that it wasn't really suited to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

We are running a high-traffic socket service on Cloud Run and have encountered no issues.  The only piece of advice I'd give you is to configure the instance to "CPU is always allocated" as it will be cheaper if you have any significant use of the service.